# Unwanted visible background in bordered element

Tags: html, css

I need red left sqare to fill 100% height of parent element (el. with red border) like this:

[image]

but on my notebook (full hd, scale in chrome 100%) it looks like this:

[image]

If you can see there is visible background black on top and left side that red square. (If your render is like pic.1 you can scale up/dow scale in browser)

How can i to reach render like picture 1?

Here fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dLnj6394/

HTML:

```
<div class="line">
  <div class="year">a
  </div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="year">a
  </div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="year">a
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.year {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine for me - Firefox 92.0 on Windows 10

Comment: @Rojo yep on this same notebook in FF is okay for me too...

Comment: Google Chrome 94.0.4606.61 (latest) is showing up fine as well...

Comment: Try to add 'height: 40px;' to '.year'

Comment: This phenomenon comes and goes with zoom level at least on Chrome/Edge on Windows10. It's a sort of rounding effect when the calculated CSS px value doesn't exactly map to a whole number of screen pixels (there are several screen pixels per CSS px on HD screens).

Comment: @Azu it had this property...

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you. I suppose something like that. Is there some name of this phenomenon? Is there some way to force filling this space?

Comment: @Lajdak, Sorry, I had in mind to add 'height: 40px;; to .line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly hacky workaround is to give the line elements a stripe of red on the left as background so there is no black to show when you get the 'rounding error' of split pixels.

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0 50px, transparent 50px 100%);
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.line {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.year {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="year">a
  </div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="year">aa
  </div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="year">a
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that okay now? How do you see it in the browsers?